# Extract Codes from string text

Tags: python, regex, text-mining

I have a created a pandas database which has a feature which contains thousands of documents (1 per indexed row).  Within the document, billing codes can be found.  These can be found anywhere within the document (beginning, end, middle, and multiple instances from within a single document).  They begin with a letter and are followed by up to 6 characters (generally numbers, sometimes another letter).  I have compiled a list of the codes which are possible (these are an industry wide set of coding).  My thought is to use the list of codes similar to a stopwords list.  Except instead of excluding the codes, leave only the codes.  Then append these in their own column of the dataframe, while keeping them indexed the same as the original dataframe.  I cannot post sample data, because of industry regulation.  I'm not positive this is a regex issue, and I'm open to any solution in Python (preferably).

Example document:

```
blah blah blah code1 blah blah code(n) blah
```

Desired data frame outcome:

```
1 |id# |Orignial Document |code1 code(n)|
2 |id#2|document 2        |code2 code(k)|
3 |id#3|document 3 blahs  |nan          |
```

The code list:

```
[ code1, code2,..., code(n),...code(k)]
```

I made some progress, i have the following code

```
def match(input_string, icd_codes):
words = re.findall(r'\w+', input_string)
if [x for x in words if x in icd_codes]:
    return [x for x in words if x in icd_codes]
else: 
    return [np.NaN]
```

Then when you run the function

```
y= str(df['Diagnosis'])
df['ICD']= pd.Series(data=match(y,icd_codes))
df['ICD']
```

It outputs

```
Code
Code2
Code
Code(n)
.
.
.
NaN
NaN
```

Ultimately, I think the code needs to wrap up something like so:

```
df['ICD']=df.Diagnosis.apply(lambda f: match(f,icd_codes))
```

Its only pulling about 25 codes (way too few and all seem to come from last 30 documents) and they are also indexed inappropriately.  I am having trouble figuring out how to get it to run on the entire column of documents and concatenating the output in a new column (while maintaining the integrity of the index).  What I want to happen is have a NaN or blank appear if the document indexed 1 in "Diagnosis" does not have code in the text.  Then the code appear in the new column indexed the same.  I was able to extract a few more codes by passing the documents into a list using df.iterrows().  However, the described function and subsequent calling of it still ignores the need for the integrity of the original indexing to remain.  I'm very stuck on this problem.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "_I'm not positive this is a regex issue_" - why not? To me, this is exactly a regex job. BTW, your "list" is a set. A list must be enclosed in square brackets.

Comment: I wasn't as precise as I should've been.  In my code it is square brackets.  Also, just to clarify, the "blah" could be anything, not just the same string repeated.  Otherwise this would be incredibly simple.  I thank you for the edits and for reinforcing the use of regex.

Comment: @StephenDeWolfe as DyZ asked, why not regex?

Comment: I meant that I was open to other solutions if anyone had one.